# How to bind the Mouse wheel to a tkinter canvas object, object using tag_bind?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, binding

I was wondering if theres anyway that I could bind the mousewheel event to a canvas rectangle for example.
When I want to do that with other events I use the tag_bind method from the Canvas class, however it seems that that method doesnt work with the mousewheel event.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Zoom_rectangle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, p0, w, h):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.p0 = p0
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        id = canvas.create_rectangle(p0[0], p0[1], p0[0]+w, p0[1]+h,
        fill="light blue")
        canvas.tag_bind(id, "<ButtonRelease>", self.fun)

    def fun(self, event):
        print(event)


class Gui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        w = 500
        h = 500
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=w, height=h)
        canvas.pack()
        Zoom_rectangle(canvas, (50,50), 400, 100)
        Zoom_rectangle(canvas, (50,200), 400, 100)


root = tk.Tk()
gui = Gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to find a way to do the same but with the MouseWheel event instead of the ButtonRelease event.

Comment: Bind MouseWheel event to canvas, check whether the mouse is inside the rectange.  If inside, fire `fun()` with the MouseWheel event.  Does the above work in your situation?

Comment: What you say would work, the thing is that the class that creates the rectangle I want the mousewheel to be bind to is not the main class. The class takes the canvas object as an input and then draws the elements into it. Because many instances of the class can be put in the same canvas then the method you presents becomes not that easy. Do you know any way I could do what I ask? If not then I would do what you suggest somehow

Comment: Ive edited the question to ilustrate what Im saying

Comment: Try using virtual event: add `canvas.tag_bind(id, '<<MouseWheel>>', self.fun)` in `Zoom_rectangle`.  Then bind `<MouseWheel>` event to canvas in class `Gui`: `canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.onMouseWheel)` and call `event.widget.event_generate('<<MouseWheel>>', x=event.x, y=event.y, time=event.delta)` (use `time` to pass the mouse wheel `delta` value) in `onMouseWheel(self, event)` function.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks alot man I didnt know you could do that, that was helpful